# Keyboard shortcut to place tasktags in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tags, keyboard, task

Is there any keyboard shortcut for placing task tags in eclipse like the TODO / FIXME / XXX ( user-defined)

Have searched on Google and was not able to find a shortcut.

Comment: You can use the following shortcut: Slash, slash, T, O, D, O :-). Would it really be faster to type Ctrl-Shift-F9 (for example) than `// TODO`.

Comment: That was a good advice. Had a similar things on Mind, as I was doing, /* TODO */, which style format is recommended, Please let me know

Comment: ctrl-Shift-F9 not working..

Comment: ctrl-shift-F9 was just a random example, to make you realize that any shortcut would ba as long to type as // TODO.

Comment: lol... Thank you for making me realize the importance of shortcuts and for a good laugh, which made me think, simple is always better

Comment: @JBNizet You should post this as an answer to this question, then. :)

Comment: How to poast that as an answer??

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I did not find any TODO shortcut but a possible solution is to create a template so when you write some string and hit Ctrl + spacebar and Enter your TODO code will be entered.

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates -> New

- Set the Name of the template (e.g. todo)
- Set the Pattern (e.g.    //TODO)

When you type todo and press Ctrl + spacebar and Enter `// TODO` will be inserted

Such a trivial todo is useless but you can tweak it by using variables as shown in the picture. Use "Insert Variable" button to insert variables.

[image]

When you use the pattern shown in the picture following will be inserted:

`// TODO inserted by UserName [21. 1. 2015, 13:07:07]`

---

More about Java Editor Template Variables can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-template-variables.htm)

Comment: Note: When creating a new template, by default, context will be set to AspectJ Templates... Be sure to change it to Java